# How to make the system duplicate a page when a new user registers

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

My idea is to have a sample page, when a user registers he will fill that sample, but I will create that sample just one time, and I want Joomla to create a copy of that empty sample with different URL each time a new user registers.

I'm thinking if there is any macro extension for joomla that can do that, do you know any?
Without that, I needed to create a sample or duplicate it myself each time a user registers and that's crazy!

- Do you know any extension to duplicate the page each time the user registers?
- There is any way that I can manipulate the system to do that?

Comment: Can you give more information about the sample page please? Do you mean they complete a form with something like profile information?

Comment: Like a facebook profile, they will fill that.
Like I create a page with some sections, the first user registers and go to that page, fill it and save, that's easy to do.
What I want is each time a user registers, Joomla duplicate that empty page, then the user fills and so on, each time someone registers get that page to fill.

Comment: I still can't figure out the difference between a profile information page and your duplicated 'empty page'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you `might` be looking for something like Jomsocial. At registration, the user fills in information about themselves, which is then made available on their profile page.

Here is an example of the information that can be showed on their profile page  http://www.jomsocial.com/community/101675-thanh/profile.html

Another extension similar to that would be Community builder. **EDIT:** Here is some more information on the registration and profile  https://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder#vtabs27

If I have misunderstood, can you write more about what your sample page is trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do!
But I don't know idea how to do that.

Comment: Ok, I will get the extension and try to solve my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: @R.Costa If my answer solves your question, please select it as the answer for this question. If you want to wait for better answers, that is ok too :)